# Restarting my android service?

Tags: android, service

I want to restart my android service if some preferences have changed, but there's nothing like a restart method in the Service class? Is there any way to restart my service, except creating some kind of reset method that resets all class variables etc. ? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

I think that calling it again, will call onStartCommand() again.
This might do the work for you.

*it will run onCreate() if it's not alive.

Call startService(intent) again, that will do the trick

Comment: well, I actually want the service to be restarted, even if it is already running. I especially want onCreate() to be called again. BTW I want to restart the service from inside itself.

Comment: I am not sure, and really don't know how a service can start itself. It can killself() but as for restart? i am lost. what about the Activity ? how about a broadcastlistener that gets called from the onclose() and than starts it again? just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `override` the `onStartCommand()` in your service class as follows:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The constant variable `START_STICKY` indicates the system to restart the service if it get killed.

You should have/implement a `listener` to detect and inform when preference changes and you should register for that listener inside `onStart()` method and un-register that listener inside `onDestroy()`.